# How to SSH directly to target via jumphost using SSH Config without additional ssh command

Tags: linux, ssh

If I do:

```
ssh -J jumphost.example.com target.example.com
```

I end up immediately logged on to 'target'.

If I use this ssh config file, using the newer ssh-7.3 jump config:

```
Host jump 10.1.*, targets*, *.example.com
  HostName jumphost.example.com
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I end up logged into 'jumphost' not 'target'

They keychain stuff is for mac, I have tested without it and it makes no difference but thought I'd leave it in just in case.

Comment: `-J` is `ProxyJump` and not `HostName`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You end up logged in to the jump host because your configuration explicitly says to ignore the hostname you specified and log in to the jump host.

```
  HostName jumphost.example.com
```

`HostName` overrides the hostname specified on the command line.

If you are trying to automatically use a jump host without having to specify it on the ssh command line, the correct config file option is `ProxyJump`. For example:

```
Host everything, behind, jumphost, *.example.com
  ProxyJump jumphost.example.com
```

Now you can just run `ssh target.example.com` and you will go through the jumphost.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the Host definition catches both jumphost.example.com AND target.example.com as aliases, it then sets HostName to jumphost.example.com in both cases.

I would suggest making the aliases following the Host command NOT fully qualified domain names, then creating a Host entry for each